# Optimizing a complex query

Tags: mysql, explain

I'm trying to optimize the longest query I've ever written using the MySQL `EXPLAIN` but since this is my first I can't seem to understand the result. Here's the query and the result from running an `EXPLAIN` command:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT pb.name, s1.MessageFrom, s1.MessageText, s1.SendTime, s1.is_unread, s1.Id, s1.autoreply_sent FROM sol_inbound s1
    JOIN sol_contactnum c ON s1.MessageFrom = c.number
    JOIN sol_phonebk_contactnum USING (contactnum_id)
    JOIN sol_phonebk pb USING (phonebk_id)
    JOIN sol_message_folder mf ON s1.Id = mf.message_id
    WHERE (MessageFrom, SendTime) IN (SELECT MessageFrom, MAX(SendTime) FROM sol_inbound inb
        JOIN sol_message_folder mf WHERE inb.Id = mf.message_id
        AND mf.folder_id=1 AND mf.direction='inbound' AND mf.user_id=1
        GROUP BY MessageFrom)
    AND mf.folder_id=1 AND mf.direction='inbound' AND mf.user_id=1
    UNION
    SELECT NULL `name`, s1.MessageFrom, s1.MessageText, s1.SendTime, s1.is_unread, s1.Id, s1.autoreply_sent FROM sol_inbound s1
    LEFT JOIN sol_contactnum c ON s1.MessageFrom = c.number
    JOIN sol_message_folder mf ON s1.Id = mf.message_id
    WHERE c.number IS NULL
    AND mf.folder_id=1 AND mf.direction='inbound' AND mf.user_id=1
    AND (MessageFrom, SendTime) IN (SELECT MessageFrom, MAX(SendTime) FROM sol_inbound inb
        JOIN sol_message_folder mf WHERE inb.Id = mf.message_id
        AND mf.folder_id=1 AND mf.direction='inbound' AND mf.user_id=1
        GROUP BY MessageFrom)
    ORDER BY SendTime DESC LIMIT 100
```

The`EXPLAIN` results in:

```
 id  select_type         table                   type    possible_keys                                                  key               key_len  ref                                                     rows  Extra                   
------  ------------------  ----------------------  ------  -------------------------------------------------------------  ----------------  -------  ----------------------------------------------------  ------  ------------------------
     1  PRIMARY             pb                      ALL     PRIMARY                                                        (NULL)            (NULL)   (NULL)                                                   303                          
     1  PRIMARY             sol_phonebk_contactnum  ref     PRIMARY,phonebk_id1_idx,contactnum_id1_idx,phonebk_contactnum  PRIMARY           4        googlep1_solane.pb.phonebk_id                              1  Using index             
     1  PRIMARY             c                       eq_ref  PRIMARY,number_idx                                             PRIMARY           4        googlep1_solane.sol_phonebk_contactnum.contactnum_id       1                          
     1  PRIMARY             s1                      ref     PRIMARY,message_from_idx                                       message_from_idx  243      googlep1_solane.c.number                                   1  Using where             
     1  PRIMARY             mf                      eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                        PRIMARY           22       const,googlep1_solane.s1.Id,const,const                    1  Using where; Using index
     2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  inb                     index   PRIMARY                                                        message_from_idx  243      (NULL)                                                     1                          
     2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  mf                      eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                        PRIMARY           22       const,googlep1_solane.inb.Id,const,const                   1  Using where; Using index
     3  UNION               s1                      ALL     PRIMARY                                                        (NULL)            (NULL)   (NULL)                                                   877  Using where             
     3  UNION               c                       ref     number_idx                                                     number_idx        243      googlep1_solane.s1.MessageFrom                             1  Using where; Using index
     3  UNION               mf                      eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                        PRIMARY           22       const,googlep1_solane.s1.Id,const,const                    1  Using where; Using index
     4  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  inb                     index   PRIMARY                                                        message_from_idx  243      (NULL)                                                     1                          
     4  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  mf                      eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                        PRIMARY           22       const,googlep1_solane.inb.Id,const,const                   1  Using where; Using index
(NULL)  UNION RESULT        <union1,3>              ALL     (NULL)                                                         (NULL)            (NULL)   (NULL)                                                (NULL)  Using filesort
```

The `UNION` in the middle of the query joins those who's numbers appear in the phonebook with those who don't (thus the `LEFT JOIN`).

**Edit:**

What this query does is get the most latest Inbound message for each number and returns it. I can use `GROUP BY` since it returns the oldest message...I need the latest. Then it joins it those numbers which don't exist in the phonebook which is why I check for `WHERE c.number IS NULL.`

Comment: What version of MySQL? From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html: "When you precede a statement with the keyword EXPLAIN, MySQL displays information from the optimizer about the query execution plan. That is, MySQL explains how it would process the statement, including information about how tables are joined and in which order."

Comment: Version 5.0.10 I assume. Whatever version ships with the latest XAMPP.

Comment: Based on the explain plan, I'd guess this query is pretty fast. Is it giving you problems? I guess I'm not quite sure what the question is.

Comment: So your question is "how to use the output of EXPLAIN to optimize the query"?

Comment: Can you rewrite the query without USING. It's too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Where possible, use an uncorrelated subquery as follows...

```
FROM... x
JOIN 
   ( SELECT MessageFrom
          , MAX(SendTime) max_sendtime
       FROM sol_inbound inb
       JOIN sol_message_folder mf 
         ON inb.Id = mf.message_id
      WHERE mf.folder_id=1 
        AND mf.direction='inbound' 
        AND mf.user_id=1
      GROUP 
         BY MessageFrom 
   ) y
  ON y.messagefrom = x.messagefrom
 AND y.max_sendtime = x.sendtime
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have used 2 `sub-query's` to filter the results, these are not really needed. I assume you need to display the `latest message` from each `MessageFrom` id.

Try this for faster results

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  ( SELECT 
    pb.name, 
    s1.MessageFrom, 
    s1.MessageText, 
    s1.SendTime, 
    s1.is_unread, 
    s1.Id, 
    s1.autoreply_sent,
    @row_num := IF(@prev_value=s1.MessageFrom,@row_num+1,1) AS row_num,
    @prev_value := s1.MessageFrom
  FROM 
    sol_inbound s1
    JOIN sol_contactnum c ON s1.MessageFrom = c.number
    JOIN sol_phonebk_contactnum USING (contactnum_id)
    JOIN sol_phonebk pb USING (phonebk_id)
    JOIN sol_message_folder mf ON s1.Id = mf.message_id
  WHERE 
      mf.folder_id=1 
      AND mf.direction='inbound' 
      AND mf.user_id=1
  ORDER BY
    s1.MessageFrom,
    s1.sendTime desc ) temp WHERE temp.row_num = 1

UNION

SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  (     
    SELECT 
      NULL `name`, 
      s1.MessageFrom, 
      s1.MessageText, 
      s1.SendTime, 
      s1.is_unread, 
      s1.Id, 
      s1.autoreply_sent,
      @row_num := IF(@prev_value=s1.MessageFrom,@row_num+1,1) AS row_num,
      @prev_value := s1.MessageFrom 
    FROM 
      sol_inbound s1
      LEFT JOIN sol_contactnum c ON s1.MessageFrom = c.number
      JOIN sol_message_folder mf ON s1.Id = mf.message_id
    WHERE 
        c.number IS NULL
        AND mf.folder_id=1 
        AND mf.direction='inbound' 
        AND mf.user_id=1
    ORDER BY
      s1.MessageFrom,
      s1.sendTime desc      
        ) temp2 WHERE temp2.row_num = 1

ORDER BY 
  SendTime DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

Instead of using a `sub-query` to filter the results, I have utilized `session vars` in Mysql to keep rank all messages of a `MessageFrom`. The one having the `latest sendtime` has the `rank` as `1`